# imagettftext wont work; text doesn't show up

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to use the `imagettftext()` to add text to an image via PHP. So far I've gone through about 6 different tutorials, trying to get it to work, and I have had no success. I'm currently trying this code from the php documentation page.

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

However, nothing shows up. I have the GD library installed, as well as freetype enabled. I have `arial.ttf` in the same directory as the php file, and I cannot figure out why it wont work. All I get is a blank image.

EDIT: This is the error message "[19-Jan-2014 16:31:07] PHP Warning:  imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in /var/www/php/bb/test.php on line 21"

Comment: Please log the errors to a file and post them here, `ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "php-error.log");`Don't forget to create the file `php-error.log`in the same dir as your script and give it write permissions.

Comment: I got this error "[19-Jan-2014 16:31:07] PHP Warning:  imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in /var/www/php/bb/test.php on line 21
[19-Jan-2014 16:31:08]". I definitely have arial.ttf in the same directory, so I'm not sure why that's happening

Comment: I tested your exact code, and its working

Comment: Yeah, I've tried so many different variations by going to different tutorials and c/p the completed code. Nothing works. I don't know what's going wrong

Comment: NVMIND I got it working. I added "putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));" in front of the $font

Answer (score 0):

I was about about to tell you to type the real path of the ttf instead of the relative path.

```
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
```

or

```
$font = '/home/user/arial.ttf';
```